# WildCard Not Working In Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I am trying to open a file and awk the first line from a file in Ksh
the file is as follows

```
dbld/prod/run/ingest.???????.out|head -1
```

This wild Card Substitution Works fine in Terminal but However when I do it from a Shell Script(ksh), It says

> File Cannot be Found

Comment: I assume dbld/prod/run/ingest.???????.out is a compiled program?  What else is your script doing?  Can you post a minimal version that still fails?  Thanks

Comment: @rojomoke means: The commandline given is missing the command `cat`.
When the command is working, the *.out file must be an executable script/program. 
When the *.out file is a plain outputfile, you should write  
`cat dbld/prod/run/ingest.???????.out|head -1` or `head -1 file`